# How to handle migrations in a big project?

Tags: python, django, django-models

i am currently working backend on a project with django and i have been facing problems with migrations mainly because i don't know when to make new migrations at all or only migrate the model i want, and my main problem is when i make a new branch do my work and migrate then merge it with develop the 0001 initial migrations make problems and conflict so i have to drop everything and repeat. Any help would be amazing.

I tried creating a migrations.sh that removes migrations and database and migrates every model but surely this isn't the right way.

Comment: "_removes migrations and database_" you should never delete the migrations! That kind of workflow is suitable only if you aren't ever going into production. If you are developing and haven't merged the migrations in your branch then maybe you can delete the newly created migrations if you made a mistake etc.

Comment: so should i put my migrations in gitignore so when the server recieves the new models changes the makemigrations and migrate happens there?

Comment: I've linked a duplicate target that explains that, but you should absolutely **commit the migration files** to your version control. Also you're running the `makemigrations` on the server side?? Creating the migration files is part of the **development** workflow. In the deployment side only `migrate` should be run out of the two commands.

Comment: I don't see why you should remove migrations, or why many migrations is a problem: if you migrate, Django will *topologically sort* the migrations, which runs in *O(n)*, so that is not much of a problem.